# Karma install failing on rebuild npm node.js

Tags: node.js, angularjs, vcbuild, karma-runner

So i'm tryin to get karma working on my Windows 7 machine and I'm continuing to have trouble.

I'm using node.js 0.10.7 and using the command npm install -g karma. The first issue was missing vcbuild, so I installed http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11310 and added it to my path.  Now I'm getting the below error during rebuild:

> C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\nod
>   e_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws>node "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_mo
>   dules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   rebuild
>
> **..\src\bufferutil.cc(55): warning C4267: 'initializing' : conversion from 'size
>   _t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data ..\src\bufferutil.cc(66): warning C4267: 'initializing' : conversion from 'size
>   _t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data C:\Users\Steve.node-gyp\0.10.6\deps\v8\include\v8.h(184): warning
>   C4506: no de finition for inline function 'v8::Persistent
>   v8::Persistent::New(v8::Hand le)'**
>
> **LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\Users\Steve.node-gyp\0.
>   10.6\node.lib'**
>
> **Project : warning PRJ0018: The following environment variables were not found: C:\Users\Steve.node-gyp\0.10.6\deps\v8\include\v8.h(184):
>   warning C4506: no de finition for inline function 'v8::Persistent
>   v8::Persistent::New(v8::Hand le)'**
>
> **LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\Users\Steve.node-gyp\0.
>   10.6\node.lib'**
>
> **Project : warning PRJ0018: The following environment variables were not found: C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Roaming\npm\karma ->
>   C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Roaming\npm\n ode_modules\karma\bin\karma**
>
> karma@0.8.5 C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma ├──
>   pause@0.0.1 ├── dateformat@1.0.2-1.2.3 ├── xmlbuilder@0.4.2 ├──
>   colors@0.6.0-1 ├── mime@1.2.9 ├── growly@1.1.1 ├── chokidar@0.6.2 ├──
>   q@0.9.3 ├── coffee-script@1.6.2 ├── rimraf@2.1.4 (graceful-fs@1.2.1)
>   ├── minimatch@0.2.12 (sigmund@1.0.0, lru-cache@2.3.0) ├──
>   optimist@0.3.5 (wordwrap@0.0.2) ├── LiveScript@1.0.1
>   (prelude-ls@1.0.0) ├── glob@3.1.21 (inherits@1.0.0, graceful-fs@1.2.1)
>   ├── log4js@0.6.5 (dequeue@1.0.3, semver@1.1.4, async@0.1.15,
>   readable-stream@1.0 .2) ├── lodash@1.1.1 ├── http-proxy@0.10.2
>   (pkginfo@0.2.3, utile@0.1.7) ├── istanbul@0.1.22 (abbrev@1.0.4,
>   which@1.0.5, fileset@0.1.5, wordwrap@0.0.2, n opt@2.0.0, async@0.1.22,
>   mkdirp@0.3.5, esprima@0.9.9, escodegen@0.0.22, handleba rs@1.0.11) └──
>   socket.io@0.9.14 (base64id@0.1.0, policyfile@0.0.4, redis@0.7.3,
>   socket.io-c lient@0.9.11)

The LINK errors are in read and that directory is missing.  The other bold font are warnings.  I haven't had problems with node.js, but trying to run karma fails. Any ideas? This is based on the [AngularJS tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the installer wants the file "C:\Users\Steve\node-gyp\0.10.6\node.lib", you just have to give it that file.

1. Open the "C:\Users\Steve\node-gyp\0.10.6" directory.
2. Within that directory, there should be "ia32" and "x64" subdirectories - open the correct one for your architecture.
3. There should be a "node.lib" file within the subdirectory - simply copy that file to the parent directory (C:\Users\Steve\node-gyp\0.10.6).
4. Re-run "node install -g karma"

Once I did that, the karma build still reported a few warnings but no errors.

To continue with the tutorial, you'll want to add the npm module directory (typically C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm) to your PATH.

Comment: Sweet this worked. The install i did was from angular so the cmd was "npm install -g karma" I also needed to create %CHROME_BIN% in system vars to get Karma working in chrome in case anyone else has a similar problem.